# how can fetch data into laravel foreach without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

how can fetch data into laravel foreach every 1 min without reload page
in my app price of product in DB change every 1 min from api. i need to change price of product in my foreach in blade every 1 min without reloading page

my foreach

```
 @foreach ($products as $product )
   {{$product->id}}
   {{$product->name}}
   {{$product->price}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: use Ajax in setInterval();

Comment: Make yourself familiar with *polling*, *longpolling*, *server send events* and / or *websockets*

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadCasting.

This [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting) maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show any data without reloading the page it must be done by jquery. it may be ajax or WebSocket. if you use the post method server use may increase. so try to use WebSocket. when your API hit then saves and broadcasts the data. in HTML using jquery change the data.

https://pusher.com
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting